# Possbile to test percent of Ethyl Alcohol in hand sanitizer?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

The percent of Ethyl Alcohol in hand sanitizers slowly drops over time. And manufacturers put an expiration date on the bottles. But I'd to test the percent of Ethyl Alcohol for myself for a new bottle and to see how much over time is lost as it gets close to the expiration data and beyond. Is this possible for a chemistry n00b?

Comment: If the alcohol is simply lost via evaporation and diffusion, just measure the weight or the liquid level of the bottle.

Comment: Flammability (actually, flash-point): https://ask.metafilter.com/95484/At-what-proof-will-spirits-burn

Comment: Note that there equally are sanitizers based on isopropyl alcohol _instead_ of ethanol.